# Remove "Everyone" from aws s3 object ACL's using .NET API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm looping through all object ACL's in a bucket, to remove "Everyone" permissions from all of them.  The idea here is to retain all current permissions.

My issue is that the PutACL call doesn't work.  In the example below, a new AccessControlList is created, omitting the "everyone" entries.  The PutACL call returns successfully, but the object's ACL is unchanged.

Perhaps there is an easier way to identify and remove specific Grants.

```
AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client();
GetACLRequest aclRequest = new GetACLRequest() { BucketName = "my-bucket", Key = "/dir/protect_me.txt" };
var aclResponse = s3.GetACL(aclRequest);

bool foundEveryonePriv = false;  //if found at least one.

S3AccessControlList newAcl = new S3AccessControlList();
foreach (var grant in aclResponse.AccessControlList.Grants)
{
    bool grantToEveryone = string.Compare(grant.Grantee.URI, "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers") == 0;
    Logger.log.InfoFormat("{0},{1},{2},{3}", aclRequest.BucketName, o.Key, grant.Permission, (everyoneHasThisPriv ? "EVERYONE" : string.Empty));

    if (grantToEveryone)
    {
        foundEveryonePriv = true;
        newAcl.AddGrant(grant.Grantee, grant.Permission);
    }
}

//modify the items if necessary and requested.
if (foundEveryonePriv)
{
    newAcl.Owner = aclResponse.AccessControlList.Owner;
    var response = s3.PutACL(new PutACLRequest() { AccessControlList = newAcl, BucketName = aclRequest.BucketName, Key = o.Key });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying the existing ACL from the GET to remove the public grant. Then send the modified ACL back in a PUT request. Here's what I did and it's working well to retain the original grants and remove the public grant from a given object.

```
    private void RemovePublicAcl(AmazonS3Client client, string bucket, string key)
    {
        var aclRequest = new GetACLRequest { BucketName = bucket, Key = key };
        var aclResponse = client.GetACL(aclRequest);
        var acl = aclResponse.AccessControlList;

        const string PUBLIC_GRANTEE = "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers";

        if (acl.Grants.Any(x =>
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Grantee.URI) &&
            x.Grantee.URI.Equals(PUBLIC_GRANTEE)))
        {
            var publicGrant = new S3Grantee();
            publicGrant.URI = PUBLIC_GRANTEE;
            acl.Grants.RemoveAll(x =>
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Grantee.URI) &&
                x.Grantee.URI.Equals(PUBLIC_GRANTEE));

            var aclUpdate = new PutACLRequest();
            aclUpdate.BucketName = bucket;
            aclUpdate.Key = key;
            aclUpdate.AccessControlList = acl;

            var response = client.PutACL(aclUpdate);
        }
```